# Is there a theorem or law stating that the expected value of a symmetrical distribution across $f(X)$ will equal $f(\bar{x})$ iff $f'=c$ across X?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have noticed that the expected value of a symmetrical distribution across $f(X)$ will equal $f(\bar{X})$ only if $f'$ is constant across X. For example, consider a uniform distribution X ranging from 2 to 4, and two functions $g(x)=x$ and $h(x)=x^{2}$. Through simulation, I an show that $E(g(X))=g(\bar{X})$ and $E(h(X))>h(\bar{X})$ (by $\bar{X}$ I mean the mean value of X, which is 3 in my example). Looking at this problem graphically, this rule makes intuitive sense to me. I am curious if there is a rigorous proof. Has this observation been documented before?

Comment: This might be related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen's_inequality

Comment: Thanks! I found it odd that the article did not cover the case where φ is concave. If φ is concave, it seems apparent that φ(E(X))>=E(φ(x)).

Comment: Did this answer your question? I still do not really understand the statement of the question, much less what it was asking.

Comment: Jenson's inequality answered the case of my question which I was actually interested in, and I would accept it as an answer. I intuitively thought that  φ(E(X))>=E(φ(x)) for a concave φ, which does not seem to be covered by Jensen's inequality.